# why is my code repeatedly printing out the line "the root is 51 repeatedly?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("************************************************\nWelcome to the cubic root estimator.\nThis estimates the value of one root of\nf(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.\n************************************************\nEnter the coefficients in the form “a b c”:\n");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c);

    if (powf(b,2)<4*a*c)
    printf("Complex Roots – cannot estimate with this program\n");
    else{
        int x, y;
        int arr[100];

            for (x=-50; x<=50; x++)
                y=(a*x*x)+(b*x)+c;

                if (y==0)
                printf("There is a root at: x =%d", x);

                else {
                    int i;
                    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
                    arr[i]= x; /*array of the values of x that dont yield y=o*/


                    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
                        {if (arr[0]<arr[i])
                         arr[0]=arr[i];


                printf("There is a root at: x =%d", arr[i]);
                }
```

when i run this code, it prints out over and over again "there is a root at 51"

Comment: Aside: use of smart quotes with `form “a b c”:`.  Recommend simple quotation marks `form "a b c":`

Comment: C is not Python. You must delimit code blocks with curly braces. Indentation is just for readability. Your loop body consists only of the statement that calculates `y`, after which `x` is 51 and `y` probably isn't 0.

Comment: Also, after the last loop, `i` is 100, but `arr[100]` isn't a valid array element -- it is one beyond the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    arr[i]= x;     

for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        if (arr[0]<arr[i])
            arr[0]=arr[i];
        printf("There is a root at: x =%d", arr[i]);
    }
```

Because you set `arr[i] = x;` and exiting your first loop x is 51 because you exit condition is `x > 50`

Comment: so how would i go about fixing this? sorry im a beginner to computer science, i really appreciate the help.

Comment: As I am not sure exactly what you want to do, the only advice I can tell you when designing small algorithm is to take a pen a paper.

Write how you want things to go on. Don't write code, write steps or instructions.

When happy with what you got and it shoud work and do what you want it to do, code it.
If it works on the first try, check again it is almost impossible.
If it doesn't, take your pen a paper and follow your program steps and write what is does with thee variables and check.